# Explain order of the phrase המאחרין לצאת מן השבת וממהרין לבא in the song כל מקדש שביעי from Fri. night Zemirot

Tags: shabbat-songs

In the Friday night *Zemirah* staring with the words כל מקדש שביעי , the 3rd paragraph has the phrase:

> המאחרין לצאת מן השבת וממהרין לבא - "Those who delay to leave the Shabbat and hurry to enter it

The order seems backwards. We sing this song Friday night at the **start** of Shabbat. Why are we first mentioning leaving Shabbat and then those who start it. Wouldn't a more appropriate phrase be:

> הממהרין לבא לשבת ומאחרין לצאת - "Those who hurry to enter Shabbat and delay leaving it"?

Comment: OK - mark as duplicat or shall I delete? Thanks. The other discussion does answer my question

Comment: My understanding is that duplicate questions are left around so that future askers are likely to find their question already in one phrasing or the other (you aren't the first duplicate to that question already).

Comment: @Yishai, [indeed](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/1902/why-arent-duplicate-questions-deleted). I love duplicates like this one: Besides the help to searchers that they provide, two documentations of the same astute observation is an inspiring demonstration of great minds  thinking alike!